# iOS GCM. After reinstalling app receives notifications from old installations

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I use **iOS** GCM. After reinstalling the application I receive notification that the application has been signed with the old token.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install app
   get GCM token:
   [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:_gcmSenderID
                                                     scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                   options:_registrationOptions
                                                   handler:_registrationHandler];
   Subscribe to a topic:
   [[GCMPubSub sharedInstance] subscribeWithToken:yourRegToken
                                        topic:@"/topics/sample-topic"
                                      options:nil
                                      handler:^void(NSError *error) {
                                        if (error) {
                                          int code = error.code;
                                          // handle the error, perform exponential backoff
                                          // to retry
                                        } else {
                                          // subscribe successful
                                        }
                                      }];
2. After send push, app receive one push
3. Delete app
4. Install app again
   get GCM token
   Subscribe to a topic
5. After send push, app receive two push!!!!!

Why I've got two push-notifications? How to unsubscribe from the old subscription?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Topic` is associated with `registration token`, every time you reinstall your app, you should get a new `registration token`, and your device will have only one token for your app. So you should not receive push notification twice, because your app only has one token. I tried to reproduce the issue with your provided steps, but I only receive one notification. It is possible that your old notification was delay, and when you send a new one, your app shows 2 notifications. Also, you can provide your HTTP request in your question.

Comment: But if I delete app and install app again I've got new token every time...

Comment: Yes, every time you reinstall your app, you will get a new token, but your app wont obtain the old one.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in GCM. Somehow the old registrations subscribed to a topic are not getting cleaned up when you delete the app. You should file a bug here https://github.com/google/gcm/issues.